# max date value from one column in comparison to another date field partitioned by id SQL BigQuery

Tags: sql, loops, date, google-bigquery, partitioning

I need to create a `custom_key` field that is a concat of `date` plus `id` columns. Each of the custom_key should hold a value in another column. This value is a max date from `last_edited_date` partitioned by id AND could not be later than `date` value itself. So when the code hits row 2, for instance, it needs to loop over the values in `last_edited_date` and pick the latest date available per id for this particular row and that is also not later than the row value of column `date` itself - and that is the tricky part. Table below:

```
date              last_edited_date       id 
2022-06-30         2022-06-27           13b 
2022-06-30         2022-06-30           13b
2022-06-29         2022-06-30           13b 
2022-06-29         2022-06-29           13b
2022-06-18         2018-05-06           74c
2022-06-18         2021-05-06           74c 
2022-06-30         2018-05-06           74c
```

Desired output is:

```
custom_key         custom_date 
2022-06-30_13b     2022-06-30
2022-06-29_13b     2022-06-29
2022-06-18_74b     2021-05-06
2022-06-30_74b     2021-05-06
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(date, '_', id) as custom_key,
    MAX(last_edited_date) AS custom_date
FROM
    `my_table`  
WHERE
     last_edited_date <= date
GROUP BY 1
```

Output is:

```
custom_key         custom_date 
2022-06-30_13b     2022-06-30
2022-06-29_13b     2022-06-29
2022-06-18_74b     2021-05-06
2022-06-30_74b     2018-05-06
```

Comment: Your query cannot give you this output if you provided us with correct sample data. `2022-06-18` in custom_date column, cannot be returned according to your sample data.

Comment: Yes. Edited. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

One of possible option would be:

```sql
SELECT date || '_' || id AS custom_key, MAX(last_edited_date) AS custom_date
  FROM (
    SELECT id, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT date) dates, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT last_edited_date) last_edited_dates
      FROM my_table
     GROUP BY 1
  ), UNNEST(dates) date, UNNEST(last_edited_dates) last_edited_date
 WHERE date >= last_edited_date
 GROUP BY 1;
```

[image]

Comment: But for `custom_key` 2022-06-30_74c I am expecting the value of `2021-05-06` as it is the max value for 74c id...

Comment: @Chique_Code, I misunderstood your requiements. Would you take a look at it again if it meets your requirements ?

Comment: Apologies, for the late response, this worked. I upvoted and accepted the answer. Thank you very much.